Listing GCP Cloud compute and disk information during GCP region unavailability
If GCP regional services are unavailable due to an event, is it still possible to list compute and disk information hosted in the unavailable region from GCP console of Cloud Shell? Information like instance name, disk names, disk type, IP address, ILB associated with the instance, VPC, tags, labels and so on so we know how exactly to recreate in another region.

I do not know the answer. I recommend always having that information on-site and backups of everything both in the cloud and on-site. Knowing how to configure an instance will not help you if you also suffer data loss. However, if a region is down, an army of people will be working to bring the region back online. Suggestion: I would not use Cloud Shell. It would be best if you had scripted commands running on a machine on-site.

In terms of backups we have that in multi-region buckets. All i need at this point is if we are still able to pull GCE instance specifications and configuration details during regional outage which can be transformed in to required format that can be fed in to multi process GCE instance creation scripts

You mention "multi process GCE instance creating scripts". I do not recommend trying to create multiple instances at one time. Some quotas might generate errors and limit the rate at which you can create resources. If you have that large of an environment, you should be working directly with Google. I recommend engaging Google Cloud engineering.

Thanks John. Verifying quotas is one of the things i have learnt and added that step as a part of implementation since there were instances of hitting that limit thats one thing to monitor for sure

Your goal is to recreate a set of resources in (different) regions.
This closely mirrors creating a set of resources in the original regions.
For both cases, it is not good practice to rely on (any) 3rd-party (cloud) provider to provide this information to you (even when the services are running without issue).
A good practice is to programmatically deploy resources (to cloud platforms). This is known as "Infrastructure as code" (IaC). Beside the benefits of being able to recreate your infrastructure at any time, and compare what's deployed to what you want, you can check IaC code into your source repository and version as you would other code.
A common (but not the only) solution to this is a called Terraform (Google has a so-called provider for Terraform) but there are cloud-specific tools (e.g. Google's Cloud Deployment Manager, Pulumi and, you can write Bash scripts.
Using an IaC solution your problem becomes simpler. When you detect that  regions are inaccessible, you point your IaC tooling at new regions and have it recreate your resources for you.
NOTE

Many IaC tools will provide a mechanism to "read" your currently deployed infrastructure as a way of boot-strapping the process.
It is good practice to run your infrastructure in multiple regions|zones so that your application doesn't fail when one or more is unavailable.


Thank you for the details. I am using something similar, yet it needs details as to instance names, disk names, other specifications and configurations that we see from Google Cloud Console. If such information is available for GCE during regional outage then it makes things much simpler for me
